# Ambiguous Column Reference with Hive/Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, join, pyspark, hive

I've the following query that i need to execute:

```sql
SELECT 
    a.uuid,
    b.uuid
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            l.uuid AS east,
            r.uuid AS west
        FROM 
            tabl1            AS l
            INNER JOIN tabl1 AS r
                USING (attr_group)
            WHERE l.uuid < r.uuid
    )                           AS ids
    INNER JOIN tabl2            AS a 
        ON (ids.east = a.uuid)
    INNER JOIN tabl2            AS b
        ON (ids.west = b.uuid)
```

The problem is, when i've the two a.uuid and b.uuid the code gives the ambigous error on uuuid.
But when i try just with a.uuid or just b.uuid the query works.

Another observation is that the query runs with hive.execute(query) but not with hive.executeQuery(query). I'm using the pyspark interpreter in Zeppelin.

The HIVE version is: 3.1.0.

Comment: rename one uuid using AS, like in the ids subquery.

Comment: @leftjoin change the uuid from "SELECT a.uuid, b.uuid ..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both columns in the final resultset have the same name. Just alias them the remove the ambiguity:

```
SELECT 
    a.uuid AS uuid_a,  --> here
    b.uuid AS uuid_b   --> and here
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        l.uuid AS east,
        r.uuid AS west
    FROM tabl1 AS l
    INNER JOIN tabl1 AS r USING (attr_group)
    WHERE l.uuid < r.uuid
) AS ids
INNER JOIN tabl2 AS a ON ids.east = a.uuid
INNER JOIN tabl2 AS b ON ids.west = b.uuid
```

Note that the parentheses around the join conditions are unnecessary - I removed them.